# What does this symbol and number mean?

Tags: tiny-tower

See my screenshot - What does the tower symbol mean in the bottom left? And/or how is it different from the symbol in the top right?  I know the top right symbol and number means how many floors you have, but the symbol and number in the bottom left is clearly different...

The numbers at the bottom: Mine in the far left one and I have 17 floors.  My friend is the middle one, and he has 40+ floors...[image: Tiny-towers]

Comment: Looks like a synchronization bug. Could it be your friend played offline?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, but why would mine be off by 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It still means the number of floors you each have. It doesn't automatically sync every time you look at that page - I have had it be behind as much as 5 floors early on when I was building a lot. I suspect it only syncs a certain number of times per day.

As for your friend - there may be a problem with him syncing - perhaps he isn't connecting to Game Center, or has been offline when it is syncing, so you wouldn't see his floors. I know that sometimes it takes a couple of days for that screen to match what I see when I view my friend's towers, or for it to match how many floors their game says they have.

Comment: oh okay, Thanks for the input! I am relatively new to the game, and couldnt find any information on that :/

Answer (score 1):

The top right is how many floors YOU have. The others are your friends. But i think you are tryig to say the one with 13 is yours, yet it says you have 17. I don't know what that means though. Sorry :3